# Arduino issues on reading inputs from some buttons

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, atmega, programming, button

I'm building a sort of joystick with atmega328p:

[image]

For the moment, I have only written the code to visualize on the OLED display if we press a button or move the joystick. Let's focus on the four buttons at left, whose result is represented by the statements UP, DOWN, R, L. If we press a button, we'll se 1 on the display, else we'll see 0.

All the buttons are correctly connected to atmega328 pins, without "false electrical contacts", but if I press them,

- UP works correctly (it is always 0 and if I press it, it becomes 1)
- R works correctly
- L does not work: it keeps always 0
- DOWN partially works: if I press it, it stays 0 forever.ù

Since I have checked the connections many times, I think that maybe I have written a code that can cause some errors or missing input values. So, how do you re-write the code to find a possible solution for making all buttons work?

**This is the part of my code that regards the buttons (and the joystick, which you may ignore):**

```
void loop() {

  // **JOYSTICK**
  int x = analogRead(JOYSTICK_X);
  int y = analogRead(JOYSTICK_Y);
  int button = !digitalRead(JOYSTICK_BUTTON);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0,0); 
  display.println("X: " + String(x)); 
  display.setCursor(0,10); 
  display.println("Y: " + String(y));
  display.setCursor(0,20); 
  display.println("P: " + String(button));

  //**BUTTONS**
  display.setCursor(60,0); //Set the cursor position for the fist line to 
  visualize
  display.println("UP: " + String(!digitalRead(UP_BUTTON))); 
  display.setCursor(60,8); //Second line
  display.println("DOWN: " + String(!digitalRead(DOWN_BUTTON))); 
  display.setCursor(60,16); //Third line
  display.println("R: " + String(!digitalRead(RIGHT_BUTTON))); 
  display.setCursor(60,24); //Fourth line
  display.println("L: " + String(!digitalRead(LEFT_BUTTON))); 
  display.display();
}
```

Comment: Use the code formatting (`<pre>`code`</pre>`) instead of quotes to format code (and remove the empty lines that then are superfluous). Also, properly indent your code, please.

Comment: The code you present should not have any issues regarding reading the digital input pins. So unfortunately the problem might be in code you are not showing such as configuring the input pins, or it can be a hardware issue. How are the buttons connected and how are the input pins set up? Do the buttons have pullup resistors or are you using internal pullups?

Comment: All the buttons are connected with pull-up resistors of 10k, and with a voltmeter I have seen that the voltage at their corresponding pins goes to 0 when they are pressed. So I have thought that maybe the code may leads to errors, for instance if I press the button while it is running the part of the loop in which that input pin is not read, but at the same time this seems strange to me...

Comment: On the previous part of the code, all button pins have been declared as input pin

Comment: Do you have some advices to try? For instance another code that may arrive at the same result etc

Comment: probably you forgot to configure the pull-up for the down button.

Comment: Show your schematic, and show your `setup()` code. Without at least that information,  we can't answer this. You've been on EE.SE long enough that you should know this.

Comment: As marcelm said, we need to see setup() code. And, at a hardware point: did you tried to change the connections between the buttons and Arduino pins? This could help to discover if the problem is in the code (there is no change) or if the problem is in the hardware (there would be a change in which pin is misbehaving). How are the wires from the buttons connected to Arduino? By the way, those solder blobs look very bad.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the suggestions.  So, first of all I'll try to exchange the button connections and the respective pins.  If that doesn't work, I'll update the post with the missing information.